# Splash screen on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I'm trying to integrate a splash screen on android studio. It doesn't work and i don't know where the problem is.
[SplashActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DpO5.png)

[activity_main.xml here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE9rr.png)

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: add your error log

Comment: posted code looks fine, but you very should post also error stacktrace, "doesn't work" isn't a sufficient description, provide more info. Personally I bet on some problem in `MainActivity2`

Comment: it might worth reading https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you have set `SPLASH_TIMOUT= 30000` but this is in milliseconds (or 30 seconds), not 3 seconds as you may expect.

Also if you building a new app, there is a new API for SplashScreen in Android since 12+:  https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen which uses fewer resources of the device and is Activity life-cycle safe.